# Python C API: when are we at the end of a Python instruction?

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

My understanding is that in `PyEval_FrameEx()`, the main loop is on each `opcode` instruction.
Has `PyEval_FrameEx` the knowledge of being at the end of a Python instruction?
Maybe there's an `opcode` for that?

Answer (score 2):

An instruction is identified by one `opcode`, so there cannot be an opcode to mark the end of instruction. The main loop in `PyEval_EvalFrameEx` loops over instructions in the frame and executes them one by one, until an error or return is encountered.

If by "Python instruction" you're referring to source constructs such as statements or lines, the closest thing you will find is the line number. See [`sys.settrace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) for details.